# Java: Synthesize sound

Tags: java, piano

I want to synthesize a violin VIBRATO sound, a vibrato is a low frequency oscillaton around the note. For example a vibrato on A440 might encompass frequency fluctuation from A430 to A450. How would I make a normal violin sound, and then add vibrato?

Thanks

Comment: I'd imagine that once you are successfully generating a violin sound, you could augment it by replacing the played frequency with the equation from this page: http://www-classes.usc.edu/engr/ise/599muscog/2004/projects/yang/

Comment: Using `javax.sound.midi`, or something else?